# how to check document id is existing in collection or not in firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am checking if a person(id) is existing in my following list then it should show Unfollow else 'Follow'. But here I am getting Unfollow even if that person(id) is not existing in my following list.
eg:how it should work, when I click on follow button that person userid will store in my users/myuserid/following / (that person userid in documents).

and my code is

> ```
>     class SaharaWid extends StatefulWidget {
>   @override
>   _SaharaWidState createState() => _SaharaWidState();
> }
>
> class _SaharaWidState extends State<SaharaWid> {
>   final String loggedUserid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
>   var mode;
>   final ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Card(
>       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
>       elevation: 8,
>       child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
>         stream: ref
>             .collection('sahara/MmORK4x2Hx39fs3fPALW/posts')
>             .orderBy('datetime', descending: true)
>             .snapshots(),
>         builder: (context, fetchedData) {
>           if (fetchedData.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
>             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
>           } else {
>             // final List<DocumentSnapshot> posts = fetchedData.data!.docs;
>             return ListView.builder(
>               itemCount: fetchedData.data.docs.length,
>               itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Column(
>                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
>                 children: [
>                   GestureDetector(
>                     child: SinglePostwid(
>                         fetchedData.data.docs[index]['post'],
>                         fetchedData.data.docs[index]['username'],
>                         fetchedData.data.docs[index]['datetime']),
>                     onTap: () {
>                       if (loggedUserid ==
>                           fetchedData.data.docs[index]['userid']) {
>                         mode = 'self';
>                       } else {
>                         final getRef = ref
>                             .collection('users/$loggedUserid/following')
>                             .doc(fetchedData.data.docs[index]['userid'])
>                             .get();
>
>                         if (getRef == null) {
>                           mode = 'Unfollow';
>                         } else {
>                           mode = 'Follow';
>                         }
>                       }
>                       Navigator.of(context)
>                           .pushNamed(OtherProfileScreen.routeName, arguments: {
>                         'userid': fetchedData.data.docs[index]['userid'],
>                         'mode': mode,
>                       });
>                     },
>                   ),
>                   // Text(fetchedData.data!.docs[index]['post']),
>                   LikeCommentWid(),
>                 ],
>               ),
>             );
>           }
>         },
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

this is my database structure

[this is my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH5Pk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for the the data to be retrieved.. Have a look at `async/await`

```
final bool isFollowing = await ref.collection('users/$loggedUserid/following').doc(fetchedData.data.docs[index]['userid']).get().then((value) => value.exists);

if(isFollowing) // User is Following
else // User is not Following
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping now working exactly as I expected.